# Using a single response handler to handle multiple web request responses coming from the back-end web-service

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

So I have the following code that is sending a bunch of requests using the same service to my asp.net webservice in the backend. The method is the same, just the data is different every time, they are sent within a for loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfDataRows; i++) {
//some code
//service,method are the same below, just body is different within each loop
app.sendToService(service, method, body, this._handleResponse.bind(this)
}
```

Then later on I have the following code that handles responses coming back:

```
_handleResponse: function(response, body, method) {

   var data = response.d.result;
        switch (method) {
          //some code with case/break with other methods
          default:
            if (response.d.statusCode === 0) {
              app.showDialog("Definitions", "Successfully updated.");
              this._requestData(this.routeData.guid);
            } else {
              //2/18/2019: added error message to display
              app.showDialog("Definitions (FAILED)", "Failed to update. " + response.d.statusMsg);
            }
            break;
        }
   }
```

Problem is, this response  handler is only written to handle one response from the back-end at a time. The way my code is written right now, once any response from any of my calls from the for loop comes back, the response handler will be called, and it will break out of it, thus leaving it unable to handle any response should there is another response came back.

How would I change the `_handleResponse` method to fix this situation so that it will wait until all responses for this method are down to break out of the `'case'` block?